# Add a sub grid and view for field update

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have added a field to the Contact entity called Website Downloads. This field is updated every time a client clicks on our website but what I want to do is have a sub grid within the Contact form that shows what this entry is each time it's updated. Then I ideally need this in a view with the contacts name and a list of the downloads so I can do an advanced find on the field. Any ideas please. PS I have tried to add a new entity that links to this field but the problem is you cannot do an OR on an Advanced find for 2 separate entities so back to square one.

Already tried a new entity but this won't work as you cannot do an OR on an Advanced Find for 2 entities.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on right track. You need a related entity to capture all the website hits, then you need a rollup field on contact record to sum up the hits.

So the associated records can be listed in a subgrid on contact form, also Advanced find queries can be done.

Rollup field can be an OOB field but it has timely job to calculate, if you want immediate rollup result it can be a custom field & plugin to accumulate.

Comment: Thanks Arun. I need to actually show what the updated field is each time though rather than a rollup. Any ideas?

Comment: @ABrazier Like I said already you can have a custom field also, then a plugin is needed to take care of the updates